# How to get auto number based on selected date

Tags: php, mysql, database, autonumber

please help me to get auto number based on selected date? i have working code for auto number but that's only for today/current date. what i want is if date options selected then auto number generated based on the date selected...

here is my sample code for current date

```
    $today=date("ymd");
    $query = "SELECT max(id) AS last FROM member WHERE id LIKE '$today%'";
    $hasil = mysql_query($query);
    $data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
    $lastNoTransaksi = $data['last'];
    $lastNoUrut = substr($lastNoTransaksi, 8, 2);
    $nextNoUrut = $lastNoUrut + 1;
    $nextNoTransaksi = $today.sprintf('.%02s', $nextNoUrut);?>
```

this is my full code with html selected date

```
<?php
require("db.php");
$today=date("ymd");
$query = "SELECT max(id) AS last FROM member WHERE id LIKE '$today%'";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
$data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
$lastNoTransaksi = $data['last'];
$lastNoUrut = substr($lastNoTransaksi, 8, 2);
$nextNoUrut = $lastNoUrut + 1;
$nextNoTransaksi = $today.sprintf('.%02s', $nextNoUrut);?>



<form method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr ><td>Date</td>
<td><input type="date" name="date" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Code</td>
<td>
<?php echo $nextNoTransaksi; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Input" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

thanks so much for you kindly help

Comment: when do you need to generate this number? before or after the form submits?

Comment: i prefer before submit..so after selected date the auto number will be generate...do you have a simple code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a date to unix timestamp and use that to generate your number.

```
$date = date('ymd', strtotime('2014-03-20'));
```

In your case

```
$date = date('ymd', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

You can also use `time()` to get the current unix timestamp and modify it

```
time() + 60*60; // current time + 1 hour
```

Comment: Hi lexmihaylov, thanks for the reply..the sample code above is working and generate autonumber ..but not working when i choose another date from date select box

Comment: Could you post your html (specifically the select box)

Comment: Hmm ... what kind of date format the input(date) produce... it is possible that the format is not compatible with the `strtotime` i that case you should either use a jquery plugin for a date picker or parse the date yourself

Comment: can you give me some example?? really sorry i'm just beginner in php and jquery :)

Comment: Hmm actually I tested it and the format should be standard. I can't see where you are handling the post params `$today=date("ymd", strtotime($_POST['date']));`

Answer (score 0):

Thank so much lexmihaylov...now its working

so i created 2 files...

1. form.php
2. autonumber.php

this form.php

```
<form method="post" action="autonumber.php">
<table align="center">
<tr><td>Date</td>
<td><input type="date" name="date" /></td>
</tr>
 <tr><td>Company</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="company" /></td>
 </tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Input" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this is the autonumber.php

```
<?php
 require("db.php");
 $today=date("ymd", strtotime($_POST['date']));
 $query = "SELECT max(id) AS last FROM member WHERE id LIKE '$today%'";
 $hasil = mysql_query($query);
 $data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
 $lastNoTransaksi = $data['last'];
 $lastNoUrut = substr($lastNoTransaksi, 8, 2);
 $nextNoUrut = $lastNoUrut + 1;
 $nextNoTransaksi = $today.sprintf('.%02s', $nextNoUrut);
 ?>

 <?php echo $nextNoTransaksi; ?>
```

Now every time i change the date it will be generated autonumber based on the date that i selected...

thanks for helping me